# Visualising Neo4j graph in a web page

Tags: d3.js, graph, neo4j

I have developed a graph database in Neo4j and I want to make a web application with the graph database in the backend. I want the entire graph that was visualised in the Neo4j browser to exactly come in the web page. I dont want to again create nodes and edges using javascript libraries such d3.js, keylines etc. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Right now you can't embed the Neo4j browser as component in a webpage.

You can export the image from the browser as SVG or PNG.

Rendering it as d3 is pretty easy though, see:

http://jexp.github.io/cy2neo/

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/#_howto_graph_visualization_step_by_step

Comment: Are there any plans to break out the `CypherResultCtrl` into a standalone angular directive/controller?